# Where are the files for IIS Express when VS2013 deploys a server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-express

I am trying to access a path in my MVC controller, and have the correct routes established.  However there is a path I'm accessing `http://localhost:11541/Controller` and am getting the error

> You don't have permission to list files in this directory.

I can only assume that there is a folder or file with the same name that IIS is "seeing" before MVC routes take the path. I want to inspect this path to make sure it's empty before I continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS Express hosts directly out of your project directory. There's no special place that it moves your code to. You'll generally only see that error when where's a folder that matches your URL path, but no actual route that matches. Without more information such as your project directory structure and the contents of your RouteConfig.cs, it's impossible to say exactly what's happening, though.

Comment: Turned out to be a routing problem, but thanks to this I did discover that the paths to each virtual directory are stored in %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress config file.